# Nginx rewrite rule is not working if hash in the url

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting, regex-lookarounds, nginx-location

I have written nginx rewrite rule to redirect all request for `/path/category` except `subcategory1`. I am using below regular expression for match and it is working fine in regex tester. However, when I am providing same regex in Nginx conf then it is not working for **negative lookahead** if url contains the `#` character. Do you have any suggestions?

[image]

**Regex tried so far:**

```
^\/path\/category(?!.*(\bsubcategory1\b)).*$
^\/path\/category(([\/#]*)(?!.*(subcategory1))).*$
```

**Rewrite Rule:**

```
rewrite ^\/path\/category(?!.*(\bsubcategory1\b)).*$ https://new.host.com permanent;
```

**Path Details:**
It should redirect to https://new.host.com which is working fine

```
/path/category
/path/category/
/path/category#/
/path/category/#/
```

skip the redirection for subcategory1 . It is not working for last 3 urls that contains hash.

```
/path/category/subcategory1
/path/category/subcategory1/
/path/category/subcategory1/dsadasd
/path/category#/subcategory1
/path/category/#/subcategory1
/path/category#/subcategory1/dadsd
```

Comment: That part of the URL that begins with the # is called the [URI fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment) and is never sent to Nginx in the original request, so Nginx cannot help you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything in the URI after # is ignored because it is supposed to be client side so it never gets to HTTP server (Nginx for instance).

Nginx regex will show abnormal behavior if a # is in the string under processing.

The part after # is called [fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment).

The fragment can be processed at client side.

You can use window.location.hash to access and process fragments.

This Javascript example transform fragment in parameters in a request to *process.html* :

```
let param = window.location.hash;
param = param.substring(1); // remove #
param = '?' + param;
console.log('param=',param);
location.href = '/process.html' + param;
```